# How do i resolve this error I am trying to compile some functions and create a static library but I am getting this error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, static-libraries

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.0: in function '_start' :

(.text+0x24): undefined reference to 'main'

Collect2: error: ld returned to 1 exit status
```

Comment: You can't compile a library. You include it and you compile that file. This error, as far as I can see, says that there is no `main` function.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full text of the command that fails.  The error is from the linker (as opposed to the compiler) and suggests you have omitted the `-c` (compile only) option from the associated command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `CMake` check if you're really compiling a library not an executable. This error can occur if you have

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

instead of

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

The latter should compile a library; a library doesn't have the `main()`.